# How to remove unnecessary logging in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I set up a separate logging for their own purposes

```
'log' => [
        'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
            ],
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['info'],
                'categories' => [
                    'mycat',
                ],
                'logFile' => '@app/runtime/logs/mycat.log'
            ]
        ],
    ],
```

Then, a specific event is logged

```
Yii::info("It's work", 'mycat');
```

After that, I expect that in the file **mycat.log** will only "It's work", but this is still being written log category of "application":

```
tail -f runtime/logs/mycat.log
```

[image]

**Question**: How to disable log for application in mycat.log?

P.S. Sorry, for my english. Sorry, sorry :(

Comment: try this one `Yii::$app->log->targets['file']->enabled = false;`

Comment: Not working ( And [info][application] still write log into app.log

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should simply disable variables logging, e.g. :

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
    'levels' => ['info'],
    'categories' => ['mycat'],
    'logVars' => [],
    'logFile' => '@app/runtime/logs/mycat.log'
]
```

Read more about [`$logVars`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-log-target.html#$logVars-detail).